# io.MultiWriter vs. golang's pass-by-value

Tags: go

I'd like to create a situation where everything set to a particular log.Logger is also appended to a particular variable's array of strings.

The variable's type implements the io.Writer interface so it should be easy to add that via io.MultiWriter to log.New(), but I seem to have run into an intractable problem: the io.Writer interface is fixed and it's impossible for the variable to reference itself given golang's pass-by-value.

Maybe it will make more sense with an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io"
import "log"
import "os"
import "strings"

var Log *log.Logger

type Job_Result struct {
    Job_ID int64
    // other stuff
    Log_Lines []string
}

// satisfies io.Writer interface
func (jr Job_Result) Write (p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    s := strings.TrimRight(string(p),"\n ")
    jr.Log_Lines= append(jr.Log_Lines,s)
    return len(s), nil  
}

func (jr Job_Result) Dump() {
    fmt.Println("\nHere is a dump of the job result log lines:")
    for n, s := range jr.Log_Lines{
        fmt.Printf("\tline %d: %s\n",n,s)
    }
}

func main() {

    // make a Job_Result

    var jr Job_Result
    jr.Job_ID = 123
    jr.Log_Lines = make([]string,0)

    // create an io.MultiWriter that points to both stdout 
    // and that Job_Result var

    var writers io.Writer
    writers = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout,jr)

    Log = log.New(writers,
       "",
       log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    // send some stuff to the log

    Log.Println("program starting")
    Log.Println("something happened")
    Log.Printf("last thing that happened, should be %drd line\n",3)

    jr.Dump()   

}
```

This is the output, which is not surprising:

```
2016/07/28 07:20:07 testjob.go:43: program starting
2016/07/28 07:20:07 testjob.go:44: something happened
2016/07/28 07:20:07 testjob.go:45: last thing that happened, should be 3rd line

Here is a dump of the job result log lines:
```

I understand the problem - Write() is getting a copy of the Job_Result variable, so it's dutifully appending and then the copy vanishes as it's local.  I should pass it a pointer to the Job_Result...but I'm not the one calling Write(), it's done by the Logger, and I can't change that.

I thought this was a simple solution to capturing log output into an array (and there is other subscribe/unsubscribe stuff I didn't show), but it all comes down to this problematic io.Write() interface.

Pilot error?  Bad design?  Something I'm not grokking?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

redefine the write function (is now pointer receiver)

```
// satisfies io.Writer interface
func (jr *Job_Result) Write (p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    s := strings.TrimRight(string(p),"\n ")
    jr.Log_Lines= append(jr.Log_Lines,s)
    return len(s), nil  
}
```

initialize

```
jr := new(Job_Result) // makes a pointer.
```

rest stays as is. This way, `*Job_Result` still implements `io.Writer`, but doesn't lose state.

The go tutorial already said, when a method modifies the receiver, you should probably use a pointer receiver, or the changes may be lost. Working with a pointer instead of the actual object has little downside, when you want to make sure, there is exactly one object. (And yes, it technically isn't an object).

Comment: Simple and elegant.  I was focusing too much on making sure the Write() signature matched that I forgot the rest.  Thanks much!